# Arcs and Curves in Java Applet

Tags: java, applet, curve

So I've been given an assignment to choose a picture and draw it using java code (mainly the drawLine and drawArc methods), and I've decided on the flamel shown in the screenshot link below.

[image]

Issue 1: The drawArc method goes (x, y, x width, y height, startAngle, arcAngle) correct? I put the picture into paint and turned on the grid, so I can get the (x,y) coords and count the height and width. However, when I run the program, the arc never starts at the (x,y) coordinates, and I always have to adjust all the numbers to move the arc to where it should be. Is there any way to fix this? Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Issue 2: The screenshot above is the result of what I've coded so far. Notice, as pointed out by the red arrow, the end of that arc moves inward, rather than ending at a slant. Compare that arc to the corresponding area of the first screenshot (of the original flamel) to get a better picture of what I mean. Basically I want a curve that flows through. I've searched around and found the Cardinal Spline (Catmull-Rom), which is exactly what I'm looking for, but I failed to find an *easy* explanation of how it works or sample code for it. The shorter the code the better (easier to understand). I use jGrasp to code, and all the "demos" and "source code" I've found have tons of compiling errors that I don't understand and don't know how to fix. I am a Java novice so if anyone can run me through the basics on how to create a curve that goes through multiple points in a Java Applet, it would be much appreciated.

Code below

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Flamel extends Applet
{
public void paint (Graphics flamel)
{
  //crown

  flamel.drawLine(217,75,217,105);
  flamel.drawLine(283,75,283,105);
  flamel.drawLine(217,105,283,105);
  flamel.drawArc(217,62,33,20,180,180);
  flamel.drawArc(250,62,33,20,180,180);

  //left wing

  flamel.drawLine(203,98,147,98);
  flamel.drawLine(233,133,216,133);
  flamel.drawLine(204,127,181,127);
  flamel.drawLine(181,127,172,118);
  flamel.drawArc(204,113,22,20,199,67);
  flamel.drawArc(158,93,25,25,190,90);
  flamel.drawArc(145,95,20,14,154,140);
  flamel.drawArc(203,65,60,67,180,90);


  //right wing

  flamel.drawLine(297,98,353,98);
  flamel.drawLine(267,133,284,133);
  flamel.drawLine(296,127,319,127);
  flamel.drawLine(319,127,328,118);
  flamel.drawArc(274,113,22,20,270,67);
  flamel.drawArc(318,93,25,25,260,80);
  flamel.drawArc(334,95,20,14,255,140);
  flamel.drawArc(236,65,60,67,270,90);

  //cross heads (top/bottom/left/right)

  flamel.drawLine(250,128,237,151);
  flamel.drawLine(250,128,263,151);
  flamel.drawLine(237,151,244,159);
  flamel.drawLine(263,151,257,159);

  flamel.drawLine(250,421,238,398);
  flamel.drawLine(250,421,263,398);
  flamel.drawLine(238,398,244,393);
  flamel.drawLine(263,398,257,393);

  flamel.drawLine(170,220,146,233);
  flamel.drawLine(170,246,146,233);
  flamel.drawLine(170,220,177,227);
  flamel.drawLine(170,246,177,240);

  flamel.drawLine(330,220,354,233);
  flamel.drawLine(330,246,354,233);
  flamel.drawLine(330,220,323,227);
  flamel.drawLine(330,246,323,240);


  //cross body

  flamel.drawLine(244,159,244,393);
  flamel.drawLine(257,159,257,393);
  flamel.drawLine(177,227,323,227);
  flamel.drawLine(177,240,323,240);


  //snake (starting upward from tail)

  flamel.drawArc(252,342,10,45,270,180);
  flamel.drawArc(240,296,6,33,90,180);
  flamel.drawArc(225,270,35,85,90,180);
  flamel.drawArc(235,218,45,45,270,90);

  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Admittedly, I don't see the point of this as an programming exercise, when the goal is concatenating dozens or hundreds of `drawLine` and `drawArc` calls. And I'm not entirely sure whether it suits as a question here. But I'll try to answer it, maybe in a broader, canonical way, hoping that it is still acceptable, even though my proposed solution will no longer contain *any* calls to `drawLine` or `drawArc`...</sub>

---

In general, you should consider the alternatives for drawing "complex" geometric objects. The `drawLine` and `drawArc` methods of the [`Graphics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) class may be used, and there may be application cases for them, but I personally consider them mainly as a legacy feature that stems from the time of Java 1.0.

There are more modern ways of representing geometric shapes in Java. Particularly, via the [`Shape`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) interface (hence the name...).

The advantage of the `Shape` interface is its increased flexibility. There are many implementations of this interface. For example, [`Line2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html), or [`Arc2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Arc2D.html), or - most importantly - [**`Path2D`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html). The latter allows to manually "build" a shape, by specifying the coordinates of line endpoints. It also supports cubic curve parts (splines - not Catmull-Rom, but Bezier), with the [`Path2D#curveTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html#curveTo-double-double-double-double-double-double-) method (and the somewhat simpler `quadTo` method). The `Path2D` class also allows you to assemble multiple shapes, arbitrarily, with the [`Path2D#append`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html#append-java.awt.Shape-boolean-) method.

Considering your application case, there is also the possibility to create a *stroked* shape, using the [`Stroke#createStrokedShape`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Stroke.html#createStrokedShape-java.awt.Shape-) method. Simply said: When you have a `Shape` that represents a single, thin line, then you can use this method to create a `Shape` that represents a **thick** like. (Note that this is different from just *drawing* the thin line with a thick stroke!).

Here is an example that paints something that resembles parts of your original painting (the red and green parts are just for pointing out what is actualy drawn there...) :

[image: Path]

Created with this code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;

public class Flamel extends Applet
{
    public void paint (Graphics gr)
    {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();

        // Create the lower, snail-like part 
        path.moveTo(100, 300);
        path.quadTo(115, 275, 100, 260);
        path.quadTo( 60, 225, 100, 200);
        path.quadTo(150, 180, 150, 150);

        // Append the upper part, which is a "perfect arc"
        Arc2D a = new Arc2D.Double(50, 100, 100, 100, 0, 180, Arc2D.OPEN);
        path.append(a, true);

        BasicStroke s = new BasicStroke(14);

        // Fill a stroked version of the path
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fill(s.createStrokedShape(path));

        // Draw the path
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.draw(path);

        // Draw a stroked version of the path:
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.draw(s.createStrokedShape(path));
    }
}
```

Actually, the hardest part will be to create these arrow-shaped ends. But if the result is only intended to look like the original, and you don't need an actual shape representing the whole outline of the drawn elements, you can simply paint these heads over the remaining parts...

---

Footnotes:

- Manually fiddling with the coordinates is still not something that I'll consider as a good programming exercise. But maybe you (or someone else who is reading this answer) takes the chance of learning about the `Shape` class in Java2D...
- For certain application cases, representing "everything" via `Shape` objects may have drawbacks - for example, when blindly creating *many* [`Line2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html) objects as drop-in replacements for `drawLine` calls, this may impose some overhead, impacting performance and memory (causing GCs). But this is certainly not applicable here.

Comment: Yes you're right, the drawArc/drawLine commands are outdated, but we're mainly using them because we're being taught Java from square one (I'm not sure if this is a good method of teaching, but it is what it is). The things you mentioned such as Line2D/Arc2D/Path2D are all brand new to me, but I think I can manage to learn it. As for fiddling with the coordinates - you're right, it's not a good programming exercise and we weren't taught to do that, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work otherwise.